# Ansible URI module and skip SSL validation

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook which looks like

```
- name: CURL post example
  uri:
    url: "https://dev-box.local/api/"
    method: POST
    body: '{
           "max_conns": 0,
           "max_fails": 2,
           "fail_timeout": "3s"
           }'
    body_format: json
    validate_certs: no
    return_content: yes
    force_basic_auth: yes
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
```

but during the execution I'm getting

```
 FAILED! => {"changed": false, "connection": "close", "content": "{\"status\":403,\"message\":\"Forbidden\"}\n", "content_length": "37", "content_type": "application/json", "date": "Thu, 03 Dec 2020 21:03:13 GMT", "elapsed": 0, "json": {"message": "Forbidden", "status": 403}, "msg": "Status code was 403 and not [200]: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden",
```

when I will do the same call as the `curl -k` from the command line on the same box as ansible it works fine.

Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be passing `force_basic_auth: yes` but no `user`, nor `password`.

Example from the Ansible docs:

```
- name: Create a JIRA issue
  uri:
    url: https://your.jira.example.com/rest/api/2/issue/
    method: POST
    user: your_username
    password: your_pass
    body: "{{ lookup('file','issue.json') }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    status_code: 201
    body_format: json
```

The 403 is usually Basic Auth failing. If it's not, it could be the API server you're running requiring some sort of authentication.

If the `curl -k` command includes something like `https://user:password@dev-box.local/api/` or the `--user <user:password>`, it should work. Or maybe it's using data from `.netrc`?

I hope this helps.

Comment: yeah - that + adding `become: true` fixed that